# Lion + Xcode 3.2.3 starting problem

Tags: objective-c, xcode, osx-lion

I just got a book for iPhone programming from the library which is based on Xcode 3.x so I want to start with that. Fortunately I updated from SnowLeopard to Lion with Xcode already installed so I didn't have problems to get it installed or running in the first place.

So I read through the HelloWorld-Example and as soon as I try to start interface builder I get the message:

```
This version of Interface Builder does not support documents of type "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Document (XIB 3.x)" targeting "iPhone/iPod touch
```

I've Xcode 3.2.3 installed and have a clue how to change to something other than XIB 3.x to make this work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you may have to install Xcode 4.

Comment: There's a great link for installing Xcode 3.2.6 in Lion [here](http://anatomicwax.tumblr.com/post/7906770311/installing-xcode-3-2-6-on-lion).

Answer (score 3):

According to this post you can't install xcode 3.x on lion (at least not successfully).
http://anatomicwax.tumblr.com/post/7906770311/installing-xcode-3-2-6-on-lion

IB won't work.  The workaround is to install xcode 3.x before upgrading to lion and then go to lion.  If you already upgraded you're out of luck.

The link does have a (hackish) workaround if you don't mind playing around with configuration files and modifying mounted images.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry if I'm being a bit harsh here, but I don't think that learning to master an outdated SDK just because you happen to have an outdated book at hand is a good idea.

Even if you'd like to stick with that book for the programming language part, you should still go ahead and use Xcode 4. It shouldn't be too hard and gets you prepared for the real world.

Comment: That is a bit harsh... but more true than harsh.  Also, check if your library has a subscription to safari online.  If so, then just use xcode 4 and a book from safari.

Comment: I'll have to switch to Xcode 4 anyway if I want to finally deploy something and I know that but Xcode 4 is new. There are (as far as I know) no books that use Xcode 4 yet and it would have made things a bit easier to stick with Xcode 3.x for a bit.

Comment: Books are always at least months behind actual development - as such, the concept of printed books is outdated itself, at least for the purpose we're talking about. They may offer a convenient way to get started, but as soon as you've managed to get your first Hello World program up and running, you should (IMHO) dump them and rely on tutorials which are available all over the web. They're usually more recent and in many cases offer practical examples which are more useful and more interesting than the boring ones in the books.

Comment: I think a good start needs much more than one's first Hello World program. You have to get to know the basic concepts as well as terminology and this is more likely to be achieved by a good book than by tutorials somewhere on the web. Tutorials are a valuable source if you have basic knowledge and/or a specific problem to solve. At least from my point of view but everyone has a different approach to leaning.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get Xcode 3.2.6 to install under Lion using the install package, but if you have it installed on another machine, all you have to do is to copy the `Developer` folder into the root folder of the startup drive. It takes longer because it has to copy approximately 11 GB, but it seems to work fine!