# iPhone Development w/ xCode 3.2.4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I just bought the book: Sams Teach Yourself iPhone Application Development in 24 Hours.

In the book it uses xCode 3.2.4, so I went ahead and tried xCode 4.3 (the current version), but I didn't understand what to do...

I then found this page...
https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action

I downloaded the version of xCode used in the book (just so I could see the same thing the book shows).

But, I'm getting two errors each having something to do with the Interface Builder...

> *"This version of Interface Builder does not support documents of type "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Document (XIB 3.x)" targeting "iPhone/iPod touch"."*

And it comes up twice for two different documents in my xCode project.

**How can i get it to work?** In the book the code I put in works just fine.

Also my Mac Version is: 10.7.3

Comment: Have you made sure that you're running the old XCode version? Aside from that, you'd be better off learning from a more updated book imho ... there are lots of resources on the internet as well

Comment: Yeah, I checked and I am running xCode 3.2.4

Comment: I've done a quick Google search for you, there are plenty of threads (in SO!) about it already, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208807/lion-xcode-3-2-3-starting-problem - in short you'll have to work with an updated Xcode (which you should anyway! don't learn an outdated IDE mind you..)

Comment: Okay,  but do you know any good tutorials on xCode 4.x

Comment: There are plenty of them in the Apple Developer Resources section

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not waste time learning anything about Xcode 3.x. That would be like learning how to build catapults and siege engines in preparation for a career in the military.

Apple completely rewrote Xcode with version 4.0, and every single thing about the user interface is totally and completely different. If you invest time learning 3.x, you will be totally lost and confused when you move up to 4.x (version 4.3. was just released, and there is yet a new version on the horizon.)

I was totally lost and confused for about 2 weeks when I made the move from Xcode 3.x to 4.x, and I do this for a living and have been using Xcode for over 6 years now.

Unfortunately, the iOS development books are behind the curve when it comes to versions of Xcode.

Do yourself a favor and set the Xcode 3 book aside and find an Xcode 4 book (an ebook might be a better choice, since they can be updated.)

Comment: Joshua Nozzi wrote a good book on Xcode 4: http://amzn.com/B005GXM5U4 Its focus is on Xcode itself, though, not the frameworks. Then again, a two-fisted approach—one book about the frameworks, one book devoted to the IDE—may be better.

Answer (score 2):

From what I just read, the xib files you have are not compatible with the newest version of Xcode.

You may learn loads by fixing this.

Don't delete the two files yet...

Will the xib documents still display in IB?

Try this:

Rename the two xib files to some other name.

*) With the old file open in IB, click View, Utilities, Show File Inspector.

Click File's Owner,  Rename

1) In toolbar click File, New, File

2) Choose User Interface, Empty, Next, Next

3) Type the name of the corresponding .h file, be case sensitive. Click Create.

4) Click File's Owner

5) With the new file open in IB, click View, Utilities, Show Identity Inspector.

6) For the class name, Use the class name in which you are attempting to fix.

7) Drag a New View object to to the canvas, right click the new view, and set a Reference to the file owner's view variable by dragging to File Owner.

At this point, you could attempt to copy all the objects out of the old xib and paste to the  new one.  Make sure you check all referencing outlets and target action stuff.

8) Delete the old files in Xcode by right clicking and choose Delete, References Only.

Let me know if this works or not.